# How to access a filesystem in java?

Tags: java, spring, filesystems

I need to iterate a folder on local machine from the server to parse some files. Is it real? If it's true, please, advise me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also have a glance at the [new package nio.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) in Java 7, with [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Many new and powerful things.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/). It can handle local filesystems, SFTP and many others. All with the same code - you just change paths to files.

```
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject directory = fsManager.resolveFile("path/to/dir");
FileObject[] files = directory.findFiles(fileSelector);

for (FileObject file : files) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I receive error when trying to do it from remote server (OS: Solaris): "org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Badly formed URI "C:/My/Files".
 at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.url.UrlFileProvider.findFile(UrlFileProvider.java:91)". 
The local machine operating system is Windows.

Comment: @DmitryB Could you show me your code? This may happen when you close the FileSystemManager...

Comment: @DmitryB Just to make it clear. Are you trying to remotely access a filesystem (access Solaris from Windows)? If you do, than I think you can't use just `C:\...` path but you have to use `SFTP` or `HTTP` protocol.

Comment: Tomas, thanks for answers. Yes, I did. Does it mean that I need to share the folder to access it?

Comment: Tomas, may be I need to use signed applet in this case?

Comment: @DmitryB You don't need anything special. Just install a SFTP server on your Solaris and than you can use this path: `sftp://[username]:[password]@[server-url]/path/to/dir`. The rest is the same - VFS does everything for you.

Comment: Tomas, you are talking about access from the client to the server, aren't you?

Comment: @DmitryB Yes. Maybe you could clarify your question and provide more information so I wouldn't say anything misleading

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect via SSH, FTP, or FTPS this can be done fairly easily. If you are talking about HTTP, the server must be set to show directories = true, and you will have to parse the http response for the directory to get the files names.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a [client server application](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1167) where the server part is installed on your client  PC and privides the clietn part (which will run on the Server PC) with the needed information. Alternativly you can use FTP Server on the client machine and access it from the server when needed.